# Updating label Control immediately

Tags: c#

My program is receiving data by serial port and I want to show it(the data) by label control.receiving datas are updating consecutive.

How can I refresh value of label immediately?

Comment: Can you please be more specific ? As you receive the value you would have to set it on the label control and refresh the label control.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Most likely your application and the serial port communications are on the same thread, so the class that is listening and reading the data received via the serial port is blocking the UI.  You should probably push the serial port communications to a background thread.  Take a look at the `BackgroundWorker` class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you must do:

first: call your function in new thread :

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(yourfunction));
t.Start();
```

second:  you must invoke the Label from your form :

```
void yourfunction()
{
    while (..) // I think you have a loop in your function
    {
        if (this.label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(
            new changeLabelDelegateMethod(changeLabelText), label1, "your text");
        }
        else
            label1.Text = "your text";
    }
}
delegate void changeLabelDelegateMethod(Label l, string text);
void changeLabelText(Label l, string text)
{
        l.Text = text;
}
```